# @CreatedBy becomes null when updating

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have this entity:

```
@Entity
@EntityListeners( AuditingEntityListener.class  )
public class Employee  {
@Id
@GeneratedValue
int id;
private String name;
 ...
 @LastModifiedBy
private String modifiedBy;
@CreatedBy
private String createdBy;
}
```

And i have this config class:

```
@Configuration
 @EnableJpaAuditing
  public class DataConfig {
  @Bean
  public AuditorAware<String> auditorAware() {
    return () ->  
   SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getName();
     }
    }
```

The problem is: 
When  updating entity, the created_by  becomes null.

Any help please.

Comment: Add the context and code around how it is being updated e.g. via a REST request.

Comment: Putting just `updatable = false` on that column should be fixed

Comment: @Jonathn Johx, i did it but no way. I got the same problem

Comment: @AlanHay , i update it using JPA repository.

Comment: So `modifiedBy` != null when updating? Can you check if `createdBy` is not null after reading from database?

Comment: You need to add the code where you load it, update it and save it.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to you to ensure if your spring boot app is scanning the DataConfig class.

In addition, well in case of having a REST Service (I don't know because that info is not added to the question) but bear in mind a REST Service is Stateless, and you need fetch the Authorization from the request to add it to the spring security context BEFORE executing the request.

But if your spring boot app is just a Spring MVC one with basic Authorization, be sure you have an open session once the data is updated/created